# Как очистить cookies?

Tags: python, selenium

Как проверить, действительно ли очистились cookies с помощью selenium?

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://yandex.ru/search/?&text=пирожное')
driver.delete_all_cookies()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
# ...snip...
print(driver.get_cookies()) # Можно также проверить автоматически через "if not"
```